# What's 'slug' for in Django?

Tags: django

In Django generic views, there's `slug_field`, and `slug_url_kwarg`.
In this context, what is the definition of slug?

I choose the more persuasive explanation within items of 3 dictionaries.

In Cambridge dictionary:

> A piece of metal used instead of a coin for putting in machines

In MW:

> A disk for insertion in a slot machine; especially :one used illegally instead of a coin

In Oxford:

> A part of a URL which identifies a particular page on a website in a form readable by users.

They don't seem to make sense.

Comment: The last one does make sense

Comment: Clearly the Oxford definition is the correct one here.  Are you making a joke?  Or is there information you're leaving out, which contradicts the Oxford definition in this context?

Comment: puzzled about what's the oxford's definition originated from? from insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from the publishing world from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(publishing)):

> In newspaper editing, a slug is a short name given to an article that
> is in production. The story is labeled with its slug as it makes its
> way from the reporter through the editorial process. The AP Stylebook
> prescribes its use by wire reporters (in a "keyword slugline") as
> follows: "The keyword or slug (sometimes more than one word) clearly
> indicates the content of the story."[1] Sometimes a slug also contains
> code information that tells editors specific information about the
> story — for example, the letters "AM" at the beginning of a slug on a
> wire story tell editors that the story is meant for morning papers,
> while the letters "CX" indicate that the story is a correction to an
> earlier story.[2][3] In the production process of print
> advertisements, a slug or slug line, refers to the "name" of a
> particular advertisement. Advertisements usually have several markers,
> ad numbers or job numbers and slug lines. Usually the slug references
> the offer or headline and is used to differentiate between different
> ad runs.

From there, the slug for [web publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) was born as an effort to make more semantic URLs. This is the slug as used in django:

> Some systems define a slug as the part of a URL that identifies a page
> in human-readable keywords.[4][5] It is usually the end part of the
> URL, which can be interpreted as the name of the resource, similar to
> the basename in a filename or the title of a page. The name is based
> on the use of the word slug in the news media to indicate a short name
> given to an article for internal use. Slugs are typically generated
> automatically from a page title but can also be entered or altered
> manually, so that while the page title remains designed for display
> and human readability, its slug may be optimized for brevity or for
> consumption by search engines. Long page titles may also be truncated
> to keep the final URL to a reasonable length. Slugs are generally
> entirely lowercase, with accented characters replaced by letters from
> the English alphabet and whitespace characters replaced by a dash or
> an underscore to avoid being encoded. Punctuation marks are generally
> removed, and some also remove short, common words such as
> conjunctions. For example:
>
> Original title: This, That and the Other! An Outré Collection
>
> Generated slug: this-that-other-outre-collection

Django provides a slug field, and [in its documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) provides a definition as well:

> Slug is a newspaper term. A slug is a short label for something,
> containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re
> generally used in URLs.

Comment: Got it. extends its original meanning 'An amount of alcoholic drink that is gulped or poured.' In publishing and in web, can be understood as ' get a refined part from the whole'